# ¿Cual es el error de esta consulta?

Tags: sql-server, base-de-datos, microsoft-sql

Estoy creando una función que necesita retornar un sí (0) o un no (0) para comprobar una condición. He creado esta función para simplificar mi pregunta y demostrar el error de forma más simple.

```
  create function a () returns INT
  begin

  IF (1 >0) 
     RETURN 1;
  ELSE
     RETURN 0;

  END;
```

El error que muestra es:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Necesitas declarar tu variable de retorno fura de la condición e igualmente retornarla fuera de esta:

```
create function a () 
 returns INT
 AS
  begin
  declare @r int;

  IF (1 >0) 
     SET @r = 1;
  ELSE
     SET @r = 0;

     RETURN @r;
  END;
```

Comment: Era ese el error. Muchas gracias por tu ayuda!. 